# How to do a full join between 3 tables in sql(oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 3 tables coupon, cp, mcr. I want to get all the records of coupons in tables cp and mcr where some condition exists for cp(status='active') and mcr(status='redeem'). I want all the coupons which are either active or redeemed. that info is spread in cp and mcr.

I want all the records of activity1 union activity2. I tried to achieve with right join with activity1 and activity2 but not getting it. How do I get the results I need. following is my query

```
insert into cp (coupon, phone, status)  values (8, 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'deleted');

insert into mcr (coupon, customer, coupon_code, phone, status) values (8, 'cf6a842e-6fc2-4587-88ca-46ea6424636c', 'ABCD', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'redeemed')

select coupon.id, mcr.id as mcr, cp.id as cp  
from coupon 
left JOIN mcr ON coupon.id=mcr.coupon 
LEFT JOIN cp ON cp.coupon=coupon.id 
where  mcr.status='redeemed' 
and mcr.phone='xxxxxxxxxxxx' 
and cp.status='active';


SQL> describe cp;
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COUPON                         NUMBER(38)
 PHONE                          CHAR(12)
 STATUS                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
 CREATE_TS                 NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)
 ID                    NOT NULL NUMBER(38)

SQL> describe mcr;
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COUPON                    NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 CUSTOMER                  NOT NULL CHAR(36)
 PHONE                          CHAR(12)
 COUPON_CODE                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(64)
 STATUS                         VARCHAR2(200)
 CREATE_TS                 NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
 VERIFY_TS                      TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
 REDEEM_TS                      TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
 ID                    NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
```

I have a valid record in coupon_phone but not in merchant_coupon_redeem. I don't get any results with above query.

Comment: update your question, add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: (1) You say you have tables: `users, activity1, activity2`. So why does your query use `coupon, merchant_coupon_redeem, coupon_phone` instead? (2) If you want help, sample data and expected results make your question/answer verifiable. (3) If you want `UNION` use `UNION`. (4) Format your queries sensibly, and you will find them much easier to maintain; that run-on text dump is totally illegible in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

I think following query will give you required output. but please keep some common data in tables so can fulfil result with atleast one record with these conditions.

```
select coupon.id as cid, 
       merchant_coupon_redeem.id as mcr, 
       coupon_phone.id as cp  
from coupon 
left JOIN merchant_coupon_redeem ON cid=merchant_coupon_redeem.coupon 
left JOIN coupon_phone ON coupon_phone.coupon=cid 
where merchant_coupon_redeem.status='redeemed' 
and merchant_coupon_redeem.phone='xxxxxxxxxx' 
and coupon_phone.status='active';
```

Comment: Oh for crying in a bloody bucket. The question is nonsense! How can anyone guess whether your (also run-on text dump) is a valid answer? Even if OP accepts this answer, there still won't be any clarity on whether this _correctly_ solves the problem.

Comment: PS: You haven't even offered any explanation why/how this answers the question. .... Just raw unverifiable code.